# XNA - UnauthorizedAccessException when saving xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xna, directory, file-permissions

During my game, you can save a map and store the tiles in the map into a xml file.
So far no problem. The problem starts when I try to save it it gives me a `UnauthorizedAccessException` error somehow.

The folder is located in the installation dir of my game:

> instal_dir/data/maps/

I checked to make sure, but the folder is created succesfully with the correct permissions (write, read and execute).

Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my code:

```
private void CreateXMLOfMap()
{
    List<Tile> tiles = mapContainer.GetTileList();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
    doc.AppendChild(docNode);

    XmlNode rootNode = doc.CreateElement("Map");
    doc.AppendChild(rootNode);

    XmlNode mapName = doc.CreateElement("Name");
    mapName.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("custom_map"));
    rootNode.AppendChild(mapName);

    XmlNode tilesNode = doc.CreateElement("Tiles");
    rootNode.AppendChild(tilesNode);

    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.Count; i++ )
    {
        XmlNode tileNode = doc.CreateElement("Tile");
        tilesNode.AppendChild(tileNode);

        XmlNode positionNode = doc.CreateElement("Position");
        tileNode.AppendChild(positionNode);
        XmlNode xNode = doc.CreateElement("X");
        xNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(tiles[i].GetTilePosition().X.ToString()));
        positionNode.AppendChild(xNode);
        XmlNode yNode = doc.CreateElement("Y");
        yNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(tiles[i].GetTilePosition().Y.ToString()));
        positionNode.AppendChild(yNode);

        XmlNode textureNode = doc.CreateElement("Texture");
        textureNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(tiles[i].GetTileInfo().Name.ToString()));
        tileNode.AppendChild(textureNode);

        XmlNode YFrameNode = doc.CreateElement("YFrame");
        YFrameNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(tiles[i].GetCurrentFrame().Y.ToString()));
        tileNode.AppendChild(YFrameNode);
    }

    doc.Save(Constants.MAPS_DIRECTORY);
}
```

Comment: What if you will run your game with administrator rights?

Comment: Have you tried running it as the administrator? What is the **full** path to your installation directory of your game? Is it in "Program Files"? If it is, I would suggest not writing the .xml file to your installation directory but to your "My Documents" folder or something like that.

Comment: This a good practice to separate binaries from user data. Most of time the binaries go to `c:\Program files`, while the user data go under user's `%APPDATA%`. This patterns allows to have "protected" binaries from unfortunate or malicious update, while letting each user have its own private data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the problem that caused this exception to show up. It appeard that I only included the directory, but not the file name. So it tried to store the content into the directory, instead of into a xml file.

All I had to change was to string that goes into

```
doc.Save(PATH_TO_DIR_WITH_FILE_NAME);
```

But I'll keep in my, if I continue like this, I might end up needing administrator righs, so I'll need to change it sooner or later.

Thanks all for your advice and help!

Comment: Thanks for this update! I tried with admin rights but it never worked. Also, using admin right for a simple file write seems too much.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you don't run the application as administrator and this cause an `UnauthorizedAccessException`. So you should [force the system to run it as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7). Try to change the Application Manifest File from:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
```

to:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
```

**EDIT:**

> How can I run the game with admin rights from visual studio?

Sometimes I get this excpetion when I debug an application with vs2010 even if I'm the system administrator. However if you want to debug the application as administrator try to right click visual studio icon and then *Run as Administrator*.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem, but I think, that calling Administrator rights for simple file operations is incorrect. So I manually delete exist file before saving:

```
File.Delete(mainXmlPath);
xmlDocument.Save(mainXmlPath);
```